# pqxx c++ library Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, postgresql, valgrind, libpqxx

I use `libpqxx-4.0` C++ library to work with remote Postgresql database in my project. Everything worked fine, but than I tried running my project with valgrind and got almost million error messages saying 
`Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`
and 
`Use of uninitialised value of size 8`

It seems to be occurring somewhere directly inside the library since the valgrind trace says (for example):

```
==24073== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24073==    at 0x5C2CCEF: PQconnectPoll (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.6)
==24073==    by 0x5C2DB8D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.6)
==24073==    by 0x5C2E496: PQconnectdb (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.6)
==24073==    by 0x59EE190: pqxx::connectionpolicy::normalconnect(pg_conn*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==24073==    by 0x59EE2A3: pqxx::connect_direct::do_startconnect(pg_conn*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==24073==    by 0x59E8BA0: pqxx::connection_base::init() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==24073==    by 0x448453: pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::basic_connection(std::string const&) (basic_connection.hxx:65)
==24073==    by 0x4263BC: ServerData::load_from_db() (serverdata.cpp:43)
==24073==    by 0x40CBD2: main (server.cpp:231)
```

On my side the code causing this error is

```
pqxx::connection c(get_conn_string());  // connects to the database
```

where the get_conn_string method prototype is

```
std::string ServerData::get_conn_string() const
```

Please do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong or is there something wrong with the library itself?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong, but implementing your own c++ class for `libpq` interaction is very simple. And I am sure there are no memory problems with `libpq` that valgrind can report.

Comment: I eventually did implement quite nice libpq wrapper in C++, hoever, the problem remains the same. It turned out, that the problem is caused by libssl - the OpenSSL library, which is using uninitialized variables as entropy source. At first, it seemed weird to me, but when you think about it, it makes a little bit sense. What doesn't is the fact, that libssl authors did not bother to provide some easy switch to turn this behaviour off while debugging with valgrind.